# Loop, seperate proces for the last entry (simplest solution)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about a loop if I have. Currently my code looks like this:

```
    $rtitle = "SELECT title FROM table WHERE genre='$category'";
    $ptitles = mysqli_query($connection,$rtitle) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles));
        printf('"name": "%s",', $title2->title);
```

As you can see in the last line, after the title a comma is printed.
However, I want the last entry to not have comma at the end.

Currently I am thinking about what options to use for that. I think an if statement, however, I'm not sure how I could formulate the if loop to check for the last on. I have considered using a counter, however I am not sure how well that works. Since I have several loops like this, that are dependent on each other, I would want to keep to while loop in there if that is possible.

Does anyone have any suggestion for a good approach (if anyone has an example that would be great)? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You’ve got answers already, but still a little hint: If you don’t know the number of loop iterations beforehand – then it’s much easier to figure out if you are in the _first_ loop iteration via a simple flag … so if you just output a comma _before_ each item, and just _don’t_ do it for the first item, you can achieve the same _effect_ quite simple.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the hint. Very useful. I'll consider that when I have a similar issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP built-in function `implode`:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )

Join array elements with a glue string.
```

php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$names = array();
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles)) {
   $names[] = sprintf('"name": "%s"', $title2->title);
}
echo implode(',', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push the title into an array upon each iteration, and then just implode the array after the loop:

```
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: Thanks! As indicated above, I did something similar!